# Invalid block tag: 'bootstrap_icon', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'

Tags: django, django-bootstrap3

I tried a lot but couldn't able to fix this error.

```
  TemplateSyntaxError at /myrestaurants/restaurants/1/
Invalid block tag: 'bootstrap_icon', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/myrestaurants/restaurants/1/
Django Version: 1.8.7
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid block tag: 'bootstrap_icon', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py in invalid_block_tag, line 395
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.12
Python Path:    
['/home/vaibhav/Desktop/projects/myrecommendations',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/vaibhav/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0']
Server time:    Thu, 1 Feb 2018 16:53:44 +0000
```

Actually I wanted to display a table in which 1st column should show stars given by the customers.Here is my part of code where I m getting error :-

```
 {% if restaurant.restaurantreview_set.all != 0 %}
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Rating</th>
        <th>Comment</th>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for review in restaurant.restaurantreview_set.all %}
       <tr>
        <td>{% if review.rating == 1%}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}
        {% elif review.rating == 2%}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}
        {% elif review.rating == 3%}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}
        {% elif review.rating == 4%}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}
        {% elif review.rating == 5%}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}{% endif %}</td>
        <td>{{ review.comment }}</td>
        <td>{{ review.user }}</td>
        <td>{{ review.date }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
{% else %}
  <p>Please post the review.</p>
{% endif %}
```

I tried of lot things but couldn't able to succeed.Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% load bootstrap3 %}  -- add this line at the top of your layouts file


{% if restaurant.restaurantreview_set.all != 0 %}
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Rating</th>
        <th>Comment</th>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for review in restaurant.restaurantreview_set.all %}
       <tr>
        <td>{% if review.rating == 1%}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}
        {% elif review.rating == 2%}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}
        {% elif review.rating == 3%}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}
        {% elif review.rating == 4%}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}
        {% elif review.rating == 5%}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}{% endif %}</td>
        <td>{{ review.comment }}</td>
        <td>{{ review.user }}</td>
        <td>{{ review.date }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
{% else %}
  <p>Please post the review.</p>
{% endif %}
```